# Python3 read fron character device in blocking mode

Tags: python-3.x, file, linux-device-driver

I wrote a character device driver. Now I want to use python to read from it when there is data.
However, I found that the modules "io" as well as "os" do not block upon reading. The latter even when I set os.set_blocking(fd,true).

Is there a way to access the device in blocking mode?
Or do I miss something in the device driver (tail works fine)?

```
f=io.open("/dev/tstty0","r")
while (1)
  data=str(f.read(32))
  print("mark") # <--- endless list of marks
  #do somthing
```

The read function of the device driver:

```
static ssize_t tstty_read(
  struct file *filp,
  char *buffer,
  size_t length,
  loff_t *offset)
{
  unsigned char b;
  unsigned long ofs=0;
  devConfig* dev=filp->private_data;
  if (dev)
  {
    while (fifoGet(&dev->tcp2dev,&b) && (ofs<length))
    {
      if (put_user(b,buffer+ofs))
      {
        printk(KERN_ERR "Could not copy user data");
        return -EINVAL;
      }
      ofs++;
    }
    //printk(KERN_INFO "Reading device");
    return ofs;
  }
  printk(KERN_ERR "Unknown device: %s",filp->f_path.dentry->d_iname);
  return -EINVAL;
};
```

The read function reads any bytes available from a fifo. I none is available 0 is returned.

Comment: What is `f` in `f.open`?

Comment: Oh sorry, my bad. f is "io" in this case. Structure with "os" is almost the same: os.open("dev/tstty0",os.O_RDONLY) and os.read(f,32).

Comment: Is your driver a "plain" character device driver or a TTY driver? For a TTY driver, the TTY subsystem should handle blocking/non-blocking. For a "plain" character driver with its own read file operation handler, it is responsible for handling blocking/non-blocking.

Comment: My driver is a plain character driver with my own read function. So the solution is to block within the read function of the driver until there is data?

Answer (score 0):

Kudos to Ian Abbott. A character device has to implement the ability to block a read request. The read file operation has to evaluate filp->f_flags & O_NONBLOCK to check if a client has requested blocking I/O.

This link helped me with an example:
[simple linux driver code for blocking and non-blocking read](https://gist.github.com/itrobotics/0fe54adfff5a14e2be9f)

This example works but one has to consider two more things not covered in the example: a) What to do when you want to unload the driver while in read operation (just dont do it or wake up and abort)?
b) How to abort a client caught in blocking I/O?